# Gluon Sample HelloFX Build Error (no ld.lld)

Tags: android, maven, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

I am trying to run:
~/gluon-samples/HelloFX$mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build
on a virtual Ubuntu 22.0.4 on Windows 10 Virtualbox, after failing on WSL2.

Installed in Ubuntu:

- Maven 3.8.8
- GraalVM 22.1.0.1
- openjdk 17.0.3
- Gluonfx Maven Plugin 1.0.19 (unsure how to install, just extracted it)

I cloned [gluon-samples][1] and the only change I made was in HelloFX's pom.xml, changing ${gluonfx.target} to android as the [documentation instructs][2]. I set up the following environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME = /home/grace/Downloads/graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/
GRAALVM_HOME = /home/grace/Downloads/graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/
M2_HOME=/home/grace/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.8
PATH=/home/grace/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.8//bin:/home/grace/Downloads/graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final//bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/grace/Downloads/jdk-17.0.8/bin
```

I am completely lost. I ran the pandroid build command inside HelloFX, and it manually installed Android SDK and NDK along with a bunch of other things, yet it complained about a missing NDK directory:

"Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.19:compile (default-cli) on project hellofx: Error: You specified an android NDK, but it doesn't contain /home/grace/.gluon/substrate/Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ld.lld -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]"

From this [post][3] I figured out how to "fix" this error after discovering that npk-bundle was depreciated and created a link inside ~/.gluon/substrate/Android that pointed to ~/.gluon/substrate/Android/ndk/25.2.9519653 as per the post's mitigation instructions, which did contain toolchains, but no ld.lld!! just a lot of lld, lldb, etc.